# Install Kinesis Firehose on IBM AIX

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, aix, amazon-kinesis-firehose, data-stream

I have multiple databases on IBM AIX and want to connect my databases to AWS Kinesis Firehose but the only way that I found is through Kinesis Agent which is not compatible with AIX.
I saw on some webpage that they recommended modifying Kinesis Agent's source code to be compatible with AIX.
Is there any other way that I can connect my database to AWS Kinesis Firehose?

P.S: I want to stream the data to the Redshift whenever some changes happen to my database so I have to use Kinesis Firehouse.

Thank you

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to recompile - is there an issue with AIX compilation?

Comment: I didn't try it because in the Kinesis documentation it mentioned that it's compatible with some sort of OS's which AIX is not one of them.
Have you ever try it before?

Comment: I've not used AIX in about 10 years but I dug a little further and [the Kinesis Agent](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent) is Java code.  IBM has a [variety of Java development environments](https://developer.ibm.com/javasdk/support/aix-download-service/) available for AIX.  Even if it isn't officially supported by Amazon I would try it as it should be portable.